# Create inversed datatable from object list

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable, datasource

**I have ClassGrades table that has the following fields:**
Id, ClassId, Student, Match, Science, History, English

I retrieve all of the correct rows using a function such as the following:

```
IList<ClassGrade> classGrades = ClassService.GetClassGrades(classId: 1);
```

**This list will have ClassGrade objects in it that look like this:**
Id=1, ClassId=1, Student='Mark', Math=50.6, Science=21.8, History=70.7, English=80.1
Id=2, ClassId=1, Student='Jacob', Math=70.8, Science=19.4, History=78.7, English=11.1
Id=3, ClassId=1, Student='Lauren', Math=21.9, Science=61.1, History=99.5, English=12.1
Id=4, ClassId=1, Student='Sarah', Math=81.7, Science=65.2, History=73.7, English=65.1

I need to flip these results so that the students are the columns and the subjects w/ grades are the rows and then bind it to a Grid on my page.
I figured creating a new datatable and customizing it as necessary would be the best way to do this.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

**In the end my grid needs to look something like this:**

```
            Mark    Jacob   Lauren   Sarah  
Math        50.6    70.8    21.9     81.7  
Science     21.8    19.4    61.1     65.2  
History     70.7    78.7    99.5     73.7  
English     80.1    11.1    12.1     65.1
```

Can someone give me an example of how I would take the object list of ClassGrades and dynamically create a datatable that resembles the above. 
I would prefer using linq when possible. Also, if doing this completely in sql is the preferred way I am fine with that too, but an example would be nice.

**A couple of things to note:**

- The Subjects will only ever be those 4.
- The Students can be any random amount depending on how many Students are in a class.
- For each student within a class a row is returned.

**Below is an example of where I am getting stuck:**

```
// retrieve object list
IList<ClassGrade> classGrades = ClassService.GetClassGrades(classId: 1);

// create datatable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// get list of students
var students = from s in classGrades
               select s.Student

// get list of subjects
IList<string> subjects = new List<string>() { "Math", "Science", "History", "English" };

// create columns
table.Columns.Add(subject, typeof(string));
foreach (var student in students)
{
    table.Columns.Add(student, typeof(double));
}

// create rows
foreach (var subject in subjects) 
{
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row[subject] = subject;

    foreach (var classGrade in classGrades)
    {
        // this is where I get stuck
        row[classGrade.Student] = 
    }
}
```

Comment: You may think it would be pointless, but share what you have and what it produces.

Comment: I added an example of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in LinqPad. See the attached picture for result.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace PivotDataTable
{
    class Program
    {
        public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
        {
            return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            // retrieve object list
            var classGrades = new List<ClassGrades>() {
                new ClassGrades() {Id=1, ClassId=1, Student="Mark", Math=50.6, Science=21.8, History=70.7, English=80.1},
                new ClassGrades() {Id=2, ClassId=1, Student="Jacob", Math=70.8, Science=19.4, History=78.7, English=11.1},
                new ClassGrades() {Id=3, ClassId=1, Student="Lauren", Math=21.9, Science=61.1, History=99.5, English=12.1},
                new ClassGrades() {Id=4, ClassId=1, Student="Sarah", Math=81.7, Science=65.2, History=73.7, English=65.1}
            };

            // create datatable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            // get list of students
            var students = from s in classGrades
                select s.Student;

            // get list of subjects
            var subjects = new List<string>() { "Math", "Science", "History", "English" };

            // create columns
            dt.Columns.Add("subject", typeof(string));
            foreach (var student in students)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(student, typeof(double));
            }

            // create rows
            foreach (var subject in subjects)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();
                row[0] = subject;

                foreach (var classGrade in classGrades)
                {
                    row[classGrade.Student] = Convert.ToDouble(GetPropValue(classGrade, subject));
                }

                // add row to data table
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            // to see the result in LinqPad: remark the ReadKey line, unremark the Dump line
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            //dt.Dump();
        }
    }

    class ClassGrades
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ClassId { get; set; }
        public string Student { get; set; }
        public double Math { get; set; }
        public double Science { get; set; }
        public double History { get; set; }
        public double English { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]